# Rust Macro: Expected literal

Tags: rust, string-literals, rust-macros

I'm learning macro's a bit and trying to use them to easily export my stuff into the right directory. export_to expects a string literal, and i thought that's what concat does but apparently it's not so clear.
Is this a limitation with macro's? Or is there some solution to this?

The macro expansion seems to work just fine, so i don't know what's going on.

Any tips or ideas would be much appreciated!

```rs
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! create_endpoint {
    ($route:expr, $method:expr, $in_t:ty, $out_t:ty ) => {
        #[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, TS)]
        #[ts(export, export_to = concat!("../src/lib/endpoint_defines/", $route, "/", $method, ".ts"))]
        struct __Endpoint {
          in_type: $in_t,
          out_data_type: $out_t
        }
        
        #[cfg(test)]
        #[test]
        fn __export_write_endpoint() {
          write_endpoint($method, $route);
        }
    };
}
```

```
error: expected literal
  --> src/handshake/endpoint.rs:13:34
   |
13 |         #[ts(export, export_to = concat!("../src/lib/endpoint_defines/", $route, "/", $method, ".ts"))]
   |                                  ^^^^^^
   |
  ::: src/routes/mod.rs:18:1
   |
18 | create_endpoint!("", "POST", (), ());
   | ------------------------------------ in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `create_endpoint` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a common issue with macros. It has to literally be a string literal, not just something that evaluates to a string literal. Very annoying.

Comment: Ouch, so no workaround?

Comment: Use `$route:literal` and `$method:literal` in your macro arguments: https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/minutiae/fragment-specifiers.html#literal

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't control the `TS` macro and cannot change it, this is indeed a problem. If the macro expects a literal, somethings that expands to a literal (e.g. `concat!()` won't work.

Declarative macros (`macro_rules!`) cannot solve this on their own. If you want to stick with them, you'll have to pass the whole string to the macro, which is unfortunate.

Procedural macros, however, can be of help, since they are able to concatenate literals by themselves, thus pass a ready literal to `TS`. It might be possible to use an existing crate for that, though I couldn't find any.

Comment: Thanks, i will try figuring that one out then!

Comment: Update: This worked, i just made one myself! Thank you so much!